# "Broken OOP" or how to use NavigationDrawer callbacks

Tags: android, oop, design-patterns, android-activity

I am creating app with using custom implementation of `NavigationDrawer`- [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/). This is great library that uses dynamic adding drawer into existent view hierarchy.
As far as we need Navigation Drawer to be present on all activities in our application, we can have one `BasicActivity` abstract class that initialize drawer, sets it up and do some other basic stuff which is similar for all activities.

Here is my some part of logic from my `BaseActivity`.

```
  @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l, IDrawerItem iDrawerItem) {
        Intent intent;
        int itemId = iDrawerItem.getIdentifier();
        if(itemId==getActivityTag()) {
            return;
        }
        switch(itemId){
            case DrawerConstants.PrimaryItemConstants.ALL_CATEGORIES_PAGE_INDEX:
                intent = new Intent(this,CategoryListActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case DrawerConstants.PrimaryItemConstants.LOGIN_ITEM_INDEX:
                intent = new Intent(this,LoginScreen.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }
    }
    public abstract int getActivityTag();
```

Everything seems to work good, but one problem is that we have to know about all our child inherited classes and switch between them in the statement.
So parent is aware of its children.
I think it is bad practice in terms of OOP.
Maybe there is any workarounds to solve this problem in elegant way following design patterns.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is akin to saying "links are bad in Web pages, because it means that Web pages know about other Web pages".

Comment: Couldn't you use a hashmap in `DrawerConstants` where the key is the item id? Then you would do `DrawerConstants.PrimaryItemClasses.get(itemId)`, which would then return `CategoryListActivity.class` or `LoginScreen.class` or whatever. I'm not actually sure, though, cuz I haven't worked in Java in quite some time.

Comment: Jakar, great !!!! It seems to be a great solution !! Please post your comment as an answer ! Maybe someone have a better solution to this problem. But I don't think so. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is keep a `Map` of values in your `DrawerConstants.PrimaryItemConstants` class, rather than use a `switch-case`.

```
class PrimaryItemConstants {

    static private boolean didInit = false;
    static public Map<Integer,Class> classMap = new HashMap<Integer,Class>();

    /** initializes static variables, including classMap. 
    * Can be called multiple times but will only be initialized on first call.
    */
    static public void initialize(){
        if (didInit)return;
        classMap.put(new Integer(ALL_CATEGORIES_PAGE_INDEX),CategoryListActivity.class);
        classMap.put(new Integer(LOGIN_ITEM_INDEX), LoginScreen.class);
    }

}
```

Then in your onItemClick, you would get the class from the `Map`:

```
class BaseActivity {

    /** starts the activity corresponding the the clicked IDrawerItem
    *
    *
    * @throws Exception if itemId does not have a corresponding key in DrawerConstants.PrimaryItemConstants.classMap
    */
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l, IDrawerItem iDrawerItem) {
        Intent intent;
        int itemId = iDrawerItem.getIdentifier();
        if(itemId==getActivityTag()) {
            return;
        }
        DrawerConstants.PrimaryItemConstants.initialize();
        if (DrawerConstants.PrimaryItemConstants.classMap.contains(new Integer(itemId)){
            intent = new Intent(this,DrawerConstants.PrimaryItemConstants.classMap.get(new Integer(itemId));
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            //or whatever you want
            throw new Exception("itemId "+itemId+" not found in classMap");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> So parent is aware of its children.

you don't have to. Override the methods on the children handling the specific children cases, having the `super. onItemClick` as default case for your `switch`. The parent has to handle only the cases common to the children

Comment: But in this case I also have some "common" child classes. In this case common word pretended to be ambiguous. I cannot start some abstract activity, I have to specify class explicitly.   
Seems to be no better solutions rather than do this as I previously did.